# how to clear gridview without reloading the page

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, data-binding

I have a gridview control on my asp.net page(vb.net).  I also have a "cancel" button, that when pressed, is supposed to clear the gridview of it's current contents.

However whenever the cancel button is pressed, it just reloads the page and the gridview is still there with the same data that I wanted clear.

Based on suggestions that I found on stackoverflow, I set the datasource to nothing, but that is not working.

Here is my code for the cancel button:

```
    Private Sub btnCancel_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnCancel.Click
    gvQuizReport.DataSource = Nothing
    gvQuizReport.DataBind()
End Sub
```

Any suggestions would be welcome!

Thanks

Comment: would you be opposed to using an `UpdatePanel`? this would then only reload the gridview and NOT the whole page

Comment: No I could use an update panel, I never thought of that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you have shown some interest in updatepanels, here is some starter code in case you are unfamiliar:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
            </asp:GridView>
        </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

If you already have a `scriptmanager` on your page you don't need to add another (you will get an error). if you have any problems implementing the updatepanel, feel free to post another question, there are plenty of people to help you with it

Answer (score 3):

You might try:

```
gvQuizReport.Columns.Clear()
```

though as @Leniel Macaferi said, hiding the gridview is a possible solution as well.

Comment: I think its a problem with the button...because I got rid of the datasource=nothing and databind and just made it hidden and it still reloads the page and displays the grid when pressing cancel

Answer (score 1):

The code you showed should "clear" the results, but if you do not want anything displayed, you would hide the gridview by using `gvQuizReport.Visible = False`;

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to clear without reloading the page, you could just use client side script to hide the grid object.

[jquery hide](http://jqueryui.com/demos/hide/)